# C#: String.IndexOf to FileStream.Seek

Tags: c#

having a FileStream that I read with a StreamReader (it is a very large file), how can I set the Seek position of the FileStream to the first occurrence of a certain substring so that I can start reading this large file from a given point?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's in the file? Just lines of Unicode text? Then you've got a problem.

You will never know the position of the start of a line until you've read all the previous lines at least once. Unless the file is encoded in UTF-32, each character may take a variable number of bytes to represent it. Each line will have a variable length.

The best you can do is to scan through the file once and then make note of the positions of the starts of lines, in an index.

Answer (score 4):

`FileStream` cannot do the search for you. You'll have to manually search for it. Probably you'll want to use an efficient string searching algorithm such as [Knuth Morris Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth-Morris-Pratt_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help (Building a Regular Expression Stream Search with the .NET Framework):

https://www.developer.com/design/building-a-regular-expression-stream-search-with-the-net-framework/

Answer (score 0):

If you mean first time you read the file then well you will have to read to know the position (of the particular string). Next time if content of the file is not changing you can remember this position (in some variable for use in same run of program), set stream position and start reading it.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.lock.aspx) example on MSDN

```
filestream=new FileStream(s.Substring(s.IndexOf("string"),s.Length),FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
```

Comment: that article is about locking a portion of a file. Not sure how it relates to the question?...

Comment: And I have no idea what you think that FileStream constructor is doing.